# How to simulate ActiveRecord Model.count.to_sql

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I want to display the SQL used in a count. However, `Model.count.to_sql` will not work because count returns a FixNum that doesn't have a *to_sql* method. I think the simplest solution is to do this:

```
Model.where(nil).to_sql.sub(/SELECT.*FROM/, "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM")
```

This creates the same SQL as is used in `Model.count`, but is it going to cause a problem further down the line? For example, if I add a complicated where clause and some joins.

Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: I'm building a reporting section of my app, and I want admins to be able to build queries via the admin interface, and displaying the resulting SQL seems to be the simplest way to show them what they've built. (calling inspect on an arel relationship isn't too informative).

Comment: You could do it the other way round, where you build an sql query from the params (which you can then show to your user), and then use that query to get your data instead of using the ActiveRecord `count` method.

Comment: Make sure you sanitize the crap out of everything if you go down this route, btw.

Comment: @MaxWilliams That's actually what I started to do. My ReportCounter model builds the query and then passes it to count. So I can output the query.to_s. However, the select section of SQL is wrong, and I think that may confuse people.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can try

```
Model.select("count(*) as model_count").to_sql
```

Comment: That's better. However, to match the output I get, it would need to be `Model.select('COUNT(*)').to_sql`

Comment: However, using select rather than manipulating the output text via sub, is a much nicer way of doing it, so as this gave me a better way of doing what I wanted, I've accepted this answer.

Answer (score 7):

You may want to dip into Arel:

```rb
Model.select(Arel.star.count).to_sql
```

ASIDE:
I find I often want to find sub counts, so I embed the count(*) into another query:

```rb
child_counts = ChildModel.select(Arel.star.count)
                         .where(Model.arel_attribute(:id).eq(
                                ChildModel.arel_attribute(:model_id)))

Model.select(Arel.star).select(child_counts.as("child_count"))
     .order(:id).limit(10).to_sql
```

which then gives you all the child counts for each of the models:

```
SELECT  *,
        (
          SELECT COUNT(*)
          FROM "child_models"
          WHERE "models"."id" = "child_models"."model_id"
        ) child_count
FROM "models"
ORDER BY "models"."id" ASC
LIMIT 10
```

Best of luck

UPDATE:

Not sure if you are trying to solve this in a generic way or not. Also not sure what kind of scopes you are using on your `Model`.

We do have a method that automatically calls a count for a query that is put into the ui layer. I found using `count(:all)` is more stable than the simple `count`, but sounds like that does not overlap your use case. Maybe you can improve your solution using the `except` clause that we use:

```rb
scope.except(:select, :includes, :references, :offset, :limit, :order)
     .count(:all)
```

The `where` clause and the joins necessary for the where clause work just fine for us. We tend to want to keep the joins and where clause since that needs to be part of the count. While you definitely want to remove the `includes` (which should be removed by rails automatically in my opinion), but the `references` (much trickier especially in the case where it references a `has_many` and requires a distinct) that starts to throw a wrench in there. If you need to use references, you may be able to convert these over to a `left_join`.

You may want to double check the parameters that these "join" methods take. Some of them take table names and others take relation names. Later rails version have gotten better and take relation names - be sure you are looking at the docs for the right version of rails.

Also, in our case, we spend more time trying to get sub selects with more complicated relationships, we have to do some munging. Looks like we are not dealing with where clauses as much.
[ref2](https://github.com/ManageIQ/activerecord-virtual_attributes/blob/master/lib/active_record/virtual_attributes/virtual_total.rb#L116)

Comment: That's useful. Thank you.

Comment: this doesn't remove the joins